# Covariant derivatives in the expression for the Riemann tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, connections

I've been reading about the Riemann tensor and I've realised that I've convinced myself of two mutually exclusive facts. Suppose we have a manifold with the standard Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$, and let $U$, $V$ and $W$ be vectors at some point.

First, $f(U,V,W) =  \nabla_U \nabla_V W$  is a tensor, because the covariant derivative of a tensor is a tensor. In particular $f$ is a vector when all of its arguments are given.

However, $f$ does not appear to be linear in its arguments. If $U = U^ie_i$ and $V = V^je_j$, then

\begin{align}
f(U, V, W) &= \nabla_{U^i e_i} \nabla_{V^j e_j} W \\
&= U^i \nabla_{e_i} \left(V^j \nabla_{e_j} \right) W \\
&= U^iV^j \nabla_{e_i} \nabla_{e_j} W + U^i V^j_{ \ , i}\nabla_{e_j} W.
\end{align}
But this is not the same as $U^i V^j f(e_i, e_j, W)$, which is what is demanded by linearity.

Could anyone point out what it is that I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Problem is that $\nabla(\nabla W)$ is indeed a tensor field, but it is not given by $(U,V)\mapsto \nabla_U\nabla_V W$. It is true that $\nabla W$ maps $V$ to $\nabla_VW$, but $\nabla W$ is a $\binom11$-tensor field. Hence $(\nabla\nabla W)(U,V)=(\nabla_U(\nabla W))(V)=\nabla_U(\nabla W(V))-(\nabla W)(\nabla_UV)=\nabla_U\nabla_V W-\nabla_{\nabla_UV}W$. For the latter expression it is easy to verify directly that is is tensorial.

Comment: No, $\nabla\nabla W$ is a tensor, it just is not given by the "naive" formula.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my original comment just after you responded. Am I correct in saying that the first term in your expression for $(\nabla \nabla W)(U, V)$ is not a tensor, but the sum of both terms is a tensor?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Excellent, that solves my problem. Thank you very much!