# Second Covariant Derivative Leibniz Rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, tensors

I’ve been trying to understand why

> $$\nabla_{u,v}^2 w := (\nabla(\nabla w) )(u, v) = \nabla_u{(\nabla_v w)}-\nabla_{\nabla_u v}w$$

Should be true. Is there some easy way to prove this identity? I'd like to see a proof that doesn't expand out the product in terms of it's coordinates if possible as well. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: This is answered in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1984788/covariant-derivatives-in-the-expression-for-the-riemann-tensor .

Comment: In the answer, you say that $(\nabla U(\nabla W))(V) = (\nabla_U(\nabla W(V))- (\nabla W)(\nabla_U V)$, could you please explain what is going on in that step. That is where I have been stuck for almost a week now unfortunately. I can't see why it is true, the rest of the steps make sense to me.

Comment: It is a definition of covariant derivative : For instance $(\nabla_X T)(Y)=\nabla_X(T(Y)) - T(\nabla_XY)$.

Comment: I've seen it defined like that in a few places, but that seems like an arbitrary definition. Is there some motivation behind it, is there a good reason to suppose that it should be true without having to expand out all of the indices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that we define the covariant derivative of arbitrary tensors so that it satisfies the Leibniz rule and commutes with contractions.

The term $\nabla W(V)$ is the contraction of $\nabla W\otimes V.$ The Leibniz rule tells us that 
$$\nabla_U (\nabla W \otimes V) = (\nabla_U(\nabla W)) \otimes V +\nabla W\otimes\nabla_UV.$$

Contracting this equation yields

$$\nabla_U (\nabla W (V)) = (\nabla_U(\nabla W))(V) +(\nabla W)(\nabla_UV).$$

Recalling the definition $(\nabla W)(X) = \nabla_X W,$ we can rewrite this as the desired

$$ \nabla_U(\nabla_V W) = (\nabla (\nabla W))(U,V)+ \nabla_{\nabla_U V} W.$$

Comment: Wow I feel like I've been missing something very important while reading about this if I've understood you correctly. Are you saying then that $$\nabla W \otimes V = \nabla W(V)$$? If so, can you point me to some reading to help understand that? Thanks so much for this answer :)

Comment: @user2662833: those expressions are not equal; it should be $\nabla W(V) = C(\nabla W \otimes V)$ where $C$ is [contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction). (If you're not familiar with this approach to defining derivatives of tensors, perhaps it would help to describe what definitions you *are* using?) I learnt this material from O'Neill's *Semi-Riemannian Geometry...*.

Comment: I am familiar with contractions yes. I’ve just mostly been looking at them in terms of indices. I need to figure out how they abstractly work I suppose.

Answer (score -3):

Use the *semilatus theorem* that states $\delta^i_j=\delta^j_i$ if and only if $i=j$, followed by $$\Gamma_i\oplus \Gamma_j=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\hat{\Gamma}_i$$ where $\hat{\Gamma}$ is a half-metric tensor under a morphic dilational phase. If we use this on gradient fields, we have $$\nabla \Gamma_i\oplus \Gamma_j=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\nabla_i \hat{\Gamma}_i$$
Hence, use the same for your argument. If you combine each psuedoterm correctly, you'll get $$\nabla_{u,v}^2 w := (\nabla(\nabla w) )(u, v) = \nabla_u{(\nabla_v w)}-\nabla_{\nabla_u v}w$$ as you wanted to prove!

That being said, there are alternative methods. This is the method I learnt when I did tensor field theory. Hope this helps!

Comment: What's a "half-metric tensor"? What's a "morphic dilational phase"? If you're going to use terminology so obscure that it doesn't appear anywhere else on the internet, you should explain it. As is, this comes across as nonsense. (Also, your "semilatus theorem" is plainly false.)

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand most of that.